# Program that reads a file and displays the sum and average of the numbers in the file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to solve the following problem:
Write aprogram that reads the random numbers from the file random_numbers.txt, displays the numbers, then displays the following data:
a.  The total (sum) of the numbers
b.  The number of random numbers read from the file
c.  The average value of the numbers read from the file

Here's what i Have so far

```
sum = 0
runs = 0
avg = 0

myfile = open("random_number.txt", "r")

file_contents = myfile.read()

print(file_contents)

for i in myfile.readlines():

    number = i
    sum += number

print("the sum is", sum)
```

I don't know why the sum displays 0?

Answer (score 1):

use this maybe slove your problem

```
sum = 0
runs = 0
avg = 0

myfile = open("random_number.txt", "r")
file_contents  = myfile.readlines()
for i in file_contents:
    #print(i)
    number = i
    sum += int(number)

print("the sum is", sum)
```

Comment: Why not number = int(i) reads in a more logical fashion but just my opinion.

Comment: Your opinion is great,I didn't think it through

Comment: Can you please explain how the changes you made affect the code? Also, if I try to print the file contents, it prints the numbers in a straight line with "\n" How do I print them in separate lines?

Comment: Because your txt have "\n", you need to remove "\n" at the beginning and at the end of the string
`for i in file_contents:
    i=i.strip('\n')
    print(i)
    number = int(i)
    sum += number`